# How to save a Matlab histogram as vector graphic?

Tags: matlab, vector-graphics, postscript

When saving a histogram like this:

```
x = randn(10000,1);
h = histogram(x)

saveas(gcf, 'test','epsc')
```

The resulting postscripts contains some form of raw
bitmap. That looks really ugly, when embedded in a pdf.

How can I save a histogram as a vector graphic?

Comment: I usally use `print -depsc test` and get good results. Pretty sure they are vector graphics. Does it give a better result for you? EDIT: you are right, the numbers are raster, and it shows with a moderate zoom level

Comment: The problem seems to be the transparency

Comment: Yes, it also works for me with `set(h,'FaceAlpha',1)`. Good catch! You should add that as an answer

Comment: I did, but I am still interested in better answers. I need the transparency to display multiple histograms in one plot.

Comment: I don't think EPS supports transparency. Nor does PDF. The only way to export a graphic with transparency to PDF is to "flatten" it, computing the color of each area. As far as I know, MATLAB doesn't have this possibility. This is why it exports figures with transparency in raster format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also just save the figure as a pdf which uses vector graphics.

```
x = randn(10000,1);
h = histogram(x);

% set proper paper size before generating pdf
set(gcf, 'Units', 'Inches');
pos = get(gcf, 'Position');
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'Auto', 'PaperUnits', 'Inches', 'PaperSize', [pos(3), pos(4)]);
print(gcf, 'test.pdf', '-dpdf', '-r0');
```

**Disclaimer** I use this code a lot when I embed figures in LaTeX documents but I'm pretty sure I copied it from somewhere online (possible SO).

Answer (score 2):

I found two ways to go on:

```
set(h,'FaceAlpha',1)
```

removes all transparency effects and matlab can save this as a postscript file.

Save file as svg

```
saveas(gcf, 'test','svg')
```

and import into Inkscape (or some other program of your choosing) and export from there as eps file.